# Regex: extract first and last child directories from URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I need a regular expression that matches two virtual folders; the first and the last in a given URL:

www.example.com/**first_folder**/some/additional/bunch/of/folders/**last_folder**/

so far I have this regex: `(?<!/)/[^/?#]+` but it matches all the folders :(

I need this for a rewrite rule to use in WordPress. A Quick and dirty example for rewriting http://mysite/project/1 into http://mysite/index.php?pagename=project&id=1:

```
$newrules = array();
$newrules['(project)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution i.e. not thoroughly tested with the billion possible combinations of urls etc. so take it with a grain of salt..

```
.*?/(\w+)/.*?/(\w+)/$
```

Input :

> www.example.com/first_folder/some/additional/bunch/of/folders/last_folder/

Output :

```
$1 prints first_folder
$2 prints last_folder
```

Comment: @numediaweb No prob. Just be careful becasue regexes are fragile beasts :)